# Definition of the sine integral

Tags: functions

If $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is not defined at $x=0$, why is $\operatorname{Si}(x)=\int_0^x \frac{\sin(t)}{t} \, dt$ defined at any value of $x$?

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
\sin x = {} & x - \frac{x^3} 6 + \frac{x^5}{120} - \frac{x^7}{5040} + \cdots \\
& \text{(The denominators are factorials.)} \\ {} \\
\text{So } \frac{\sin x} x = {} & 1 - \frac{x^2} 6 + \frac{x^4}{120} - \frac{x^6}{5040} + \cdots. \\ {} \\
\end{align}
$$
That last power series is perfectly well defined when $x=0,$ and in many contexts it makes sense to define $\frac{\sin x}x$ to be equal to that. However, as I mention in a comment under the answer by Parcly Taxel, we don't really need that. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

The singularity at $x=0$ is removable; the function can be defined as $1$ at that point, which makes it entire over the whole complex plane. Hence the sine integral can be defined.

Comment: Even if the singularity were not removable, one would say $ \displaystyle \operatorname{Si}(0) = \int_0^0 \cdots = 0. \qquad$